# Restore hierarchical column index when using groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using `groupby` in pandas to compute some aggregates statistics in pandas on data where columns in a data frame are organized with a hierarchical index.
For the computed statistics I want to get back to a table form in the end, where the groups are reconverted to columns with the group values, e.g. like:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A', 'a'), ('B', 'b')])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8,2), columns=index)
```

which results in e.g. this data frame

```
          A         B
          a         b
0  0.511157  0.334748
1  0.031113 -0.477456
2  0.288080 -0.258238
3  0.138467 -0.955547
4 -0.087873  0.017494
5 -0.667393  1.190039
6 -0.068245 -1.282864
7 -0.996982  0.589667
```

Now I compute the statistics using groupby and reset the index to recreate a flat data frame:

```
df.groupby([('A','a')]).mean().reset_index()
     (A, a)         B
                    b
0 -0.996982  0.589667
1 -0.667393  1.190039
2 -0.087873  0.017494
3 -0.068245 -1.282864
4  0.031113 -0.477456
5  0.138467 -0.955547
6  0.288080 -0.258238
7  0.511157  0.334748
```

How can I achieve that `('A', 'a')` becomes a part of the multi index again, hopefully in an automatic fashion? Or stated otherwise: is there a way to preserve the hierarchical column structure during the groupby operation.

Comment: IIUC you can reassign the column values to index. `dfs = df.groupby([('A','a')]).mean().reset_index()` and `dfs.columns = index`

Comment: @Abbas but in case I do a more complex grouping, would it be ensured that the order is always preserved?

Comment: try it for yourself, it shall be preserved.

Comment: @jezrael's solution looks like a more automatic and ensured way though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me work add parameter `as_index=False` to [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
print df.groupby([('A','a')], as_index=False).mean()
          A         B
          a         b
0 -0.765088 -0.556601
1 -0.628040  2.074559
2 -0.516396 -2.028387
3 -0.152027  0.389853
4  0.450218  1.474989
5  0.718040 -0.882018
6  1.932556 -0.977316
7  2.028468 -0.875167
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that this can already be controlled in the `groupby` function.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing to do is reassign back the original columns:

```
In [182]:
df1 = df.groupby([('A','a')]).mean().reset_index()
df1.columns = df.columns
df1

Out[182]:
          A         B
          a         b
0 -0.857465 -0.761948
1 -0.263677  0.538251
2  0.067710 -1.038906
3  0.345584 -0.425514
4  0.478200  0.119345
5  0.639305  0.047526
6  1.528260  1.956677
7  3.114834 -0.532462
```